# Terminal, Files, and Settings windows are completely black on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: unity, nautilus, 18.04, nvidia-geforce

[image: For a better look, This is my display when i open settings]I can't access Terminal and neither Files. I have upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 two weeks ago and I don't know how to explain this situation but when I open my Terminal or Files, both open fully black. I have a hp-pavillion series laptop with Nvidia 2 GB graphics card.

[image: here is the photo of my screen with file manager, settings and terminal open]

Comment: This started two days before out of the blue. I have edited as per your suggestion, please let me know if you can think of something. This is really bothering me.

Comment: Yes, they are black on desktop too. I have done that to show all three black l.

Comment: It's hard to tell without any details. It must be due to some change(s) you made recently (knowingly or unknowingly). Also what's your graphics card and driver? What happens if you create a new user and log in as the new user? Are you in Wayland? If so, then try switching back to Xorg.

Comment: I tried it with creating a new user. Same results. I installed unity in my Ubuntu 18.04, still same results.

Comment: Graphics card is of Nvidia and of 2 GB.